# Copy only remaining files

Tags: gulp

I would like to have a grunt task that copies only the files that have yet to be processed without having to exclude them specifically. For example: you can see in the gulpfile below I exclude `vue` files from the copy task as they have already been processed by the vue task. I would like to, instead of specifying a glop to exclude, exclude all files that a previous task has used as a src.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const clean = require('gulp-clean')
const vueify = require('gulp-vueify')

gulp.task('vue', () =>
  gulp.src('src/**/*.vue')
    .pipe(vueify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')))

gulp.task('copy', () =>
  gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/**/*.vue'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')))

gulp.task('clean', () =>
  gulp.src('dist')
    .pipe(clean()))

gulp.task('default', [ 'vue', 'copy' ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a config variable which store the path for your `src` task :

```
const conf = {
    'vue': ['src/**/*.vue'],
    'uglify': ['./src/file3.js', './src/file1.js', './src/file2.js']
}
```

You will then iterate over all array values to build the `copy` task array parameter like :

```
const target = []
target.push('src/**/*')
for (i in conf) {
    for (var j in conf[i]) {
        target.push('!' + conf[i][j])
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example :

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const clean = require('gulp-clean')
const vueify = require('gulp-vueify')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')

const conf = {
    'vue': ['src/**/*.vue'],
    'uglify': ['./src/file3.js', './src/file1.js', './src/file2.js']
}

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
    gulp.src(conf['uglify'])
        .pipe(concat('common.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});

gulp.task('vue', () =>
    gulp.src(conf['vue'])
    .pipe(vueify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')))

gulp.task('copy', () => {
    const target = []
    target.push('src/**/*')
    for (i in conf) {
        for (var j in conf[i]) {
            target.push('!' + conf[i][j])
        }
    }
    gulp.src(target)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})

gulp.task('clean', () =>
    gulp.src('dist')
    .pipe(clean()))

gulp.task('default', ['vue', 'uglify', 'copy'])
```